# Plotting data from arduino via server

Tags: arduino

I'm sorry if I'm not posting this question on the wrong part of stackexchange, but I have no idea where to go with my needs.

I have an arduino sensor that meaasures a quantity every day. The goal is to plot that data on a website provided by my school. It's only a template, very simple to use, almost like a wordpress, so it doesn't have features to plots graphs, or storing data whatsoever. We can only use text, videos, pictures...
So my plan is as follows:
- Creating a separate script on my school's server
- Send data to that server from the arduino (can do http, ftp or tcp I think)
- The script receives the data, stores it
- It plots the needed graphs, and gets them as pictures
- It replaces on the front-end website the old picture with the new one

The main problem is: I've never done that and don't even know where to start. What protocole to send the data with ? What language to write the script in ? How to put it in place ? How to generate pictures of plots from that data, and uploading it on the website ? Does it have any chance to work ? Does this method have a name I can search as a keyword ? Do you have any project doing similar things, or even tutorials ?

I'm sorry if it seem very undefined, I know nothing abot servers, and don't know where to start.
Thank you for trying to understand me !

Comment: "`The goal is to plot that data on a website provided by my school. It's only a template, very simple to use, almost like a wordpress`" - but where does it get its data from? Does it read from a file, for instance? If so, what formant? Maybe CSV? Or is there an API to provide the data? E.g can you `http://myscholl.com/measure?temp=15&wind=20...`? Is there no teacher or IT at the school who can give you more info?